# Angular $parsers is calling after both view change and model change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Look at this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fuqetoteno/edit?html,js,console,output).

I'm replacing **a** with **b** here and It's a simplified version of what I really want to do in my project.

Type something in input and look at the console. Why `doTheJob(argument)` is invoking more than once? (It's invoking by the number of input's length)

---

**FYI**, Here is what I really want to do in my project:

I want to replace Persian digits from view (۱ ۲ ۳ ۴ ۵ ۶ ۷ ۸ ۹ ۰) with Latin ones to model (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0).
here is its [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/celoxobona/edit?html,js,console,output). you can easily see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code push - in other word, add - another reference to `doTheJob` function each time a key is pressed. But the point is, you don't have to check for `keypress` - that's what Angular already does for you when tracking the model.

Instead, you can just alter `$parsers` right in your link function:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    ngModel.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
        return doTheJob(inputValue);
});
```

What you shouldn't forget to do is changing your `replacer` as well:

```
return inputValue.replace(/a/g, 'b');
```

... so that it does a replacement globally (and not just once). Here's the [**demo**](http://jsbin.com/gixobimode/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

Comment: Thank you. can you please also look at [this](http://jsbin.com/celoxobona/edit?html,js,console,output)? I thought problems are same, but apparently it's not.  
(It's going to change latin number to persian ones)

Comment: Sure, the problem over there is that your `latinNumber` variable is created too high (outside the replacer function) and isn't reset properly.

Comment: You mean now it should works fine? http://jsbin.com/celoxobona/edit?html,js,console,output  
because it's not.

Comment: No, it should be inside the replacer function. Like [here](http://jsbin.com/kabahivuvo/1/edit?html,js,console,output).